# Why does this SELECT statement's speed change drastically at a particular LIMIT amount?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm running the following simple query in MySQL:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE longitude, latitude FROM pins ORDER BY pin_id LIMIT 100000
```

This runs in about 0.08 seconds. However, if I raise the LIMIT to 120000, it takes nearly a full second to complete. I've ran multiple tests back and forth. It's very consistant, and around 100700 it can go either way, sometimes being slow and sometimes fast. Any ideas as to what's going on?

**EXPLAIN**

(with LIMIT 100000)

```
id select_type table type  possible_keys key     key_len ref  rows   Extra  
1  SIMPLE      pins  index NULL          PRIMARY 4       NULL 100000
```

(with LIMIT 200000)

```
id select_type table type  possible_keys key     key_len ref  rows   Extra  
1  SIMPLE      pins  index NULL          PRIMARY 4       NULL 200000
```

**Additional Info**

Table size: 200M
innodb_buffer_pool_size: 8G
There's another 200GB database on the server.

**UPDATE 1**

I reset my server and things appear to be fixed. Queries are taking an amount of time proportional to the LIMIT. I'd still like to know what happened though, so it doesn't happen during production.

**UPDATE 2**

There's a new problem. I tried to run the query in phpMyAdmin and it just hangs with the "Loading" message displayed. I've tried it multiple times and it seems I simply can't run the query through phpMyAdmin at all. Running it through PHP is no problem.

Comment: Please provide the output for `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for those two cases.

Comment: @RickJames Appended, and please see my updates.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (if you are using InnoDB)?

Comment: @RickJames It's 8G, but I have another very large database on the server, well over that size, with INSERTs running on it every few seconds (SELECTs only run every once in awhile). Could it be that MySQL is determining that it's best to keep as much of those humongous tables in memory as possible? I don't really know how the buffer pool works.

Comment: at some point the db'll decide there won't be enough ram to store the query result, and it'll start using disk as cache.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, the more I learn, it's looking like that may be the issue. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on `pin_id`?  Or is that the `PRIMARY KEY`?

The buffer_pool is composed of 16KB blocks.  They come from disk as needed, and are removed (roughly) in a least-recently-used (LRU) order.

Restart the server, then do these:

1. SELECT ... LIMIT 100000;  -- slow because nothing cached
2. SELECT ... LIMIT 100000;  -- fast because all the data is cached
3. SELECT ... LIMIT 120000;  -- slow because the last 20K rows not cached
4. SELECT ... LIMIT 120000;  -- fast because all the data is cached
5. SELECT ... LIMIT 100000;  -- still fast (still cached)

Since you have 8GB of buffer_pool, and 120000 rows (I assume) easily fits, we have not yet gotten to spilling from cache.  (I'm also assuming no other queries are filling up the buffer pool from this or other tables.)

Now, lets assume your table is so big that the following won't fit in the buffer_pool:

1. SELECT ... LIMIT 99999999;  -- slow because not all cached
2. SELECT ... LIMIT 99999999;  -- slow again!  because spilled from cache and stuff had to be reloaded from disk

But, you mentioned something else...  This table is only 200M.  If that is *bytes*, then my last pair of selects do not apply.  If it is *rows*, then *probably* the that is more than 8GB.

But...  You mentioned 200GB of of another database.  It's 16KB blocks also come and go from the buffer_pool.  So activity on it *may* be bumping out blocks of your table.

Comment: 200M meant 200MB, sorry. But after reading your answer, I think I realize what was happening. The other database is in use by a daemon that is frequently accessing it. I mentioned it in a comment, but I should have put it in the OP. I guess I was assuming MySQL used a first in, first out logic when deciding what to keep in the buffer pool, but maybe this is not the case? Also, I don't recall the daemon running SELECTs, only INSERTs. Shouldn't that be a determining factor? I'll run the queries, go over the daemon and report back when I have time. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, but you said LRU order? Then that's still odd. With an 8GB buffer pool, it would take a great deal of time to cycle through the whole thing, correct? I was running my queries only 10-20 seconds apart when I found the problem. I ran a few tests here and there SELECTing the whole table. Seems like it would have been in memory for quite awhile before being in a least-recently used position.